# TypeError: interpolate not a function. (In 'interpolate(this.progress,{ inputRange: [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],outputRange: })','interpolate' undefined)

Tags: react-native, react-native-stripe-api

So while updating a bunch of stuff so we could migrate from tipsi-stripe to react-native-stripe I've managed to run into this error after attempting to initialise stripe

```
 ERROR  TypeError: interpolate is not a function. (In 'interpolate(this.progress, {
              inputRange: [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],
              outputRange: [0, 1]
            })', 'interpolate' is undefined)
```

changes made to app.js

```
import stripeConfig from './config/stripe';
import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native'
///
render () {
   return (
     <StripeProvider
       publishableKey={ stripeConfig.publishableKey }
     >
       <CodePushWrapper>
         <MobXProvider>
           <MonitorApp />
         </MobXProvider>
       </CodePushWrapper>
     </StripeProvider>
   )
 }
```

app starts up and user is authenticated and all appears to be standing up then this error hits. weird thing is that if I comment the inclusion of of the StripeProvider it still has this error throw

makes me thing its probably more related to all the RN upgrades to even be able to migrate to react-native-stripe and mobile app and RN is not my best subject

anyone know where to start with this one??

I'm lost in RN hell right now!! ;);)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I followed the stack trace and came to conclusion it was likely some RN navigation library issue but also found a post re react-native-reanimated.

At some point during this project it was updated. rolled back to 1.7.0 and yarn install and project now runs clean

PHEW!!